# Is it violation of google policy?

Tags: google-signin, google-play-console, google-developers-console

I have an native android  educational app in which i want to add chat system. To reduce the size of the app I am using buddypress chat hosted on my wordpress website in webview.
Users have  to sign in my website for chat in webview through my app. Is it violation of google policy?( There are No ads in webview)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a programming question.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a programming question, it's a question for Google Customer Services.

Answer (score 0):

It is not against Google Play policies but it depends on the nature for the app.

If it is targeting children I think you will have trouble. it is mentioned in [Families Policy Requirements](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/11044265?hl=en)

> App functionality: Your app must not merely provide a webview of a website or have a primary purpose of driving affiliate traffic to a website, regardless of ownership of the website.

To avoid any issues follow this advice:

- make it clear that this (chat WebView) is a secondary feature of your app
- make sure the web view does not redirect the user to any other site or give the user unrestricted access to the web (especially if your app targeting kids)
- you should own the website/web app
- avoid these [common violations](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9899034#!?zippy_activeEl=webviews-affiliate#webviews-affiliate&zippy=)
- put the WebView on its own full screen do not make it as a part of other screen
- the website should have SSL certificate (https) ([source](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/11044265?hl=en))
- do not make the WebView transparent or have transparency
- 